# Rails: Display a button to the current_user or display other message if already booked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, devise, controller

I'm new on Ruby on Rails...

I would like to display in my app, on my meetings page:
a button "book a seat" if the current_user is not booked yet for the meeting or display info "already booked" if the current_user is already booked for the meeting. (Only the admin can create a meeting)

I'm using devise..

I know it's not hard but I don't succeed to get rid of this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

meetings.html.erb:

```
  <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default box-shadow">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <strong><%= meeting.name %></strong>
          <br><%= meeting.details %><hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <%= image_tag "place.png", heigth:15, width: 30 %> <strong><%= meeting.address %></strong><br>
          <%= image_tag "date.png", heigth:20, width: 45 %> <%= meeting.start_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>
          <hr>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <% if meeting == current_user.meetings %>
          Already booked
          <% else %>

          <%= link_to "Book a seat", meeting_participate_path(meeting), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-md btn-info' %><br>
          <% end %>
          <% else %>
          <%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
          <%= link_to "connectez-vous", new_session_path(resource_name), class:"btn btn-info" %><br />
          <% end -%>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

MeetingController.rb:

```
    def index
     @meetings = Meeting.where('start_time > ?', Time.now)
    end

  def create
    @meeting = current_user.meetings.create(meeting_params)
    if @meeting.save
      redirect_to meetings_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def participate
   meeting = Meeting.find(params[:meeting_id])
   current_user.meetings << meeting
   redirect_to meetings_path, alert: "Booked on the meeting"
 end

     private
    def set_meeting
      @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
    end

    def meeting_params
      params.require(:meeting).permit(:name, :details, :address, :start_time, :highlight, :user_id)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following steps

On the `user.rb`

```
#=> Check if already added?
def meeting_already_added?(id)
    meeting = Meeting.find(id)
    return false unless meeting
    user_meetings.where(meeting_id: meeting.id).exists?
end

#=> Pass id by following method
def can_book_meeting?(id)
    !meeting_already_added?(id)
end
```

On the `meetings.html.erb`

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> # Check user signed in?
    <% if current_user.can_book_meeting?(meeting.id) %> # current_user added already? if not then...
        <%= link_to "Book a seat", meeting_participate_path(meeting), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-md btn-info' %><br>
    <% else %>
        Already booked
    <% end %>
<% else %> # Not signed in
    Please SignIn
<% end %>
```

Add restriction for the user by added this line on the top of the controller which action needs to authenticate the user.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :participate]
```